# i18next dropdown select without reactjs

Tags: i18next

I need to create a dropdown in order to select languages in the website. I only use nodejs not react. How can I create it? My codes are at the below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWoA3.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');

const i18next = require('i18next');
const Backend = require('i18next-fs-backend');
const i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');

i18next
    .use(Backend)
    .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'tr',
        lng: 'tr',
        backend: {
            loadPath: './translate/{{lng}}.json',
        },
    });

app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next));
app.use(express.json());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const stdI18next = { t: i18next.t.bind(i18next.t) };
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', stdI18next);
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.render('test', stdI18next);
});
```

Comment: you probably need to show us the ejs template...

Comment: <form>
            <div>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeLanguage('en')">english</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeLanguage('tr')">Turkish</a>
            </div>
        </form>

        <p>
            <span><%= t("text") %></span>
        </p>